# How te disable phone scrolling in one of the pages with PWA

Tags: html, wordpress, scroll

So I have a page on wordpress that works with PWA. As a main page I have a background photo with menu, and I want to blockade scrolling in there. On other pages it should work.

I tought that when I will make a good size of background image, it will be fine, but not all of the phones has the sime resolution.

I was wondering if there is a block code for only this main page . Or maybe there is another way to stop scrolling on tablets, and phones.

Peace

Answer (score 1):

I am not getting exactly what your mean to say. What i understand is you want to stop scrolling due to your menu is going outside.

So take a div(class=root-div) as a root element of your menu block and assign a property to it

```
root-div{
 overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

i might provide you best solution if you share link of your website where you facing issue or more elaborate your issue.